# Country state concept in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is My View Page

```
 <select name="category" value="c_id" onChange="getsubcategorydetails(this.value)" style="display:">
                                                   <option value="" selected="selected" >Select Categories</option>
            <?php if(isset($categories)) : foreach($categories as $row) :?>
                <option value=<?php echo $row->c_id; ?>><?php echo $row->c_name; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach;?>
                <?php else :
                endif;
                ?>
          </select>
                 </div>
               </div>
                 </div>
                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                   <div class="input-field col s12">
                                   <tr>

                                            <td>     




    <select name=" select id="subcategory">
 <option value="" selected="selected" >Select Sub Category</option>
 <?php foreach($sub_categories as $stt): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $stt->s_c_id; ?>"><?php echo $stt->s_c_name; ?></option>
 <?php endforeach; ?> 
 </select> 
                                                </select></td>
                                                </tr>
```

This is My Controller

```
    public function getsubcategorydetails($c_id)
    {

      $c_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
      //  echo  $c_id;
        $data['sub_categories'] = $this->m_category->getsubcategorydetails($c_id);
        //print_r($data['sub_category']);
       $this->load->view('my_admin/newpost_1',$data);
    }
```

This is My Model

```
    function getsubcategorydetails($c_id='')
 {
    $this -> db -> select('*');
    $this -> db -> where('c_id', $c_id);
    $query = $this -> db -> get('subcategories');
    return $query->result();
 }
```

When i Click Category Select Box The Values returned from Controller ... But It Not Displayed On View ... What's Wrong With That .... Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

Here in my code,

1. iam posting categoryid through ajax in onchange event
2. and getting the subcategory for the categoryid from controller
3. and make the selection box in controller with the subcategory
4. and put the selection box in subcategory id.

Try this method.

View file

```
<select name="category" onChange="getsubcategorydetails(this.value)" >
 <option value=""  >Select Categories</option>
            <?php if(isset($categories)) : foreach($categories as $row) :?>
                <option value=<?php echo $row->c_id; ?>><?php echo $row->c_name; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach;?>
                <?php else :
                endif;
                ?>
</select>

<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
    <option value="" >Select Sub Category</option>
</select>
```

Controller

```
public function getsubcategorydetails($c_id)
    {

       $c_id = $this->input->post('c_id');

       $sub_categories = $this->m_category->getsubcategorydetails($c_id);

       $subcategory='<option value="" >Select Sub Category</option>';

       foreach($sub_categories as $stt)
       {

       $subcategory.='<option value="'.$stt->s_c_id.'">'.$stt->s_c_name.'</option>';

       }

       echo $subcategory;
    }
```

Model

```
function getsubcategorydetails($c_id='')
 {
    $this -> db -> select('*');
    $this -> db -> where('c_id', $c_id);
    $query = $this -> db -> get('subcategories');
    return $query->result();
 }
```

Script

```
function getsubcategorydetails(c_id)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>yourcontroller/yourfunction",
        data: {c_id:c_id},
        success: function(data) { 
            $('#subcategory').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use JQuery AJAX to fetch the subcategory details.

Currently you are following wrong coding methods like calling a codeigniter controller function on an "OnChange" event with `getsubcategorydetails($c_id)` which is not right and makes it a wrong practice. OnChange event is used to call only Javascript functions.

To manipulate DOM, use Javascript/JQuery for it. Use the controller as a relay for getting appropriate formatted data into your JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Better option is Fetch data using AJAX and Append that to dependent select box  onChange Event.